# Create image gallery using image paths stored insqlite db

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I am creating an app which i want to use to report field incidences at work.

Each incident may have one or more photos.

At this stage, i want to store the images locally on sd card and store their paths in the sqlite db.

So far i have figured out the db design and how to capture and save images on sd card and store their paths in the db.

What is challenging me now is how to dispay the images back?

I  want a set up that dispalys the incident description and the associated image(s).

I have created xml file with textview to display the incident description and a gallery to dispaly images related to that incident.

My question is how to use image paths to create a gallery...or a better suggestion...

I have written code to retrieve incidences and related images ...

Ronald

Answer (score 0):

Use a Grid View or PageViewer to display a gallery. The one thing you have to do while using this is Memory management.

Comment: hi...thanks for the suggestion...why memory mgt challenging in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Because when every app have some limitation regarding Heap allocation.... when u load images more than allocated heap space it will throw out of memory exception....

Comment: i was thinking of using a listview ..and baseadapter for inflating the custom layout xml file. will it help?

Comment: Yes definatly you can use